# PHP version to 7.4.30 with Moodle Version is 3.9 does this works fine?

Tags: php, moodle

Moodle Version is 3.9 which is running on PHP Version 7.4.19 in Linux.  If we upgrade the PHP version to 7.4.30; will the Moodle 3.9 works fine?

Comment: Php 7.5 does not exist according to the official release page: https://www.php.net/releases/index.php

Comment: its PHP 7.4.30.  will the Moodle 3.9 works fine?

Comment: The "[Moodle and PHP](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_and_PHP) documentation states: "_PHP 7.4 can be used with Moodle 3.8.3, Moodle 3.9 and later releases._" Could have looked this up yourself

Answer (score 0):

Between php maintenance (7.4.x) release there are no incompatibility, so yes it will work.

But just to be sure from [moodle 3.9 release note](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_3.9_release_notes):
PHP version: minimum PHP 7.2.0 Note: minimum PHP version has increased since Moodle 3.8. PHP 7.3.x and 7.4.x are supported too. See Moodle and PHP for details.

Answer (score 0):

W have some problems after upgrade to 7.4.30
External plugins fail, and we have some errors with cron

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).